# Parsing with ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, xml-parsing

I am new to ruby and I have a school project were I am parsing a xml file and need to get data after certain tags. I can only use core ruby. No gems

```
    pFile = File.open("myfile.mzML", "r")
    regmsLvl = "ms level\" value=\""

    pFile.each_line { |line|

    scn = line.scan(/#{regmsLvl}(\d)/)
    #what I want to do but doesn't work


    if scn == 1
        puts("Got it!")
    end
    #what I have to do to compare if == 1
    if scn != nil
        scn.each do |val|

    if val[0].to_i == 1
        puts("Got it!")

    end
    end
    end

    }
    # a sample line that I am parsing is: 
    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000511" name="ms level" value="1" />
```

This seems silly. 
line.scans out put makes scn a 2d array. How can I just have it be a string that gets overridden each pass. Or how should I change this whole thing. Any suggestions are appreciated.
puts(scn) prints out the 1 but if I do scn == 1 or scn.to_i == 1 it never gets into the if. I have tried scn.pop and scn.pop.pop

I have added a section to show what I am trying to do now.

I need to check the ms level: if 1 then get scan start time and then the binary. This is the code that I am now working with.

```
xmlfile = File.new("afile.mzML")
xmldoc = Document.new(xmlfile)


root = xmldoc.root
puts "Root element : " + root.attributes["xmlns"]


 xmldoc.elements.each("mzML/run/spectrumList/spectrum/cvParam"){
|e| if e.attributes["value"].to_i ==1
 # Now I need to get start time: @  
    ["mzML/run/spectrumList/spectrum/cvParam/scanList/scan/value"]
 # and then
    ["mzML/run/spectrumList/spectrum/cvParam/binaryDataArrayList/binaryDataArray/binary"]

end
```

}

```
<run id="ru_0" defaultInstrumentConfigurationRef="ic_0" sampleRef="sa_0" defaultSourceFileRef="sf_ru_0">
    <spectrumList count="3310" defaultDataProcessingRef="dp_sp_0">
        <spectrum id="scan=8839" index="0" defaultArrayLength="171" dataProcessingRef="dp_sp_0">
            <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000525" name="spectrum representation" />
            <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000511" name="ms level" value="1" />
            <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000294" name="mass spectrum" />
            <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000130" name="positive scan" />
            <scanList count="1">
                <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000795" name="no combination" />
                <scan>
                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000016" name="scan start time" value="5429.47" unitAccession="UO:0000010" unitName="second" unitCvRef="UO" />
                </scan>
            </scanList>
            <binaryDataArrayList count="2">
                <binaryDataArray encodedLength="1824">
                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000514" name="m/z array" unitAccession="MS:1000040" unitName="m/z" unitCvRef="MS" />
                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000523" name="64-bit float" />
                    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000576" name="no compression" />
                    <binary>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</binary>
                </binaryDataArray>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close. Assuming you can use that REXML library (which looks like it's part of the core ruby library) you should be able to do this

```
require 'rexml/document'

xmlfile = File.new("afile.mzML")
xmldoc = REXML::Document.new(xmlfile)
root = xmldoc.root

start_time = nil
binary = nil
# get the ms level
ms_level = root.elements["spectrumList/spectrum/cvParam[@name='ms level']"].attributes["value"].to_i

if ms_level == 1
  # get the scan start time
  start_time = root.elements["spectrumList/spectrum/scanList/scan/cvParam[@name='scan start time']"].attributes["value"]
  # get the binary
  binary = root.elements["spectrumList/spectrum/binaryDataArrayList/binaryDataArray/binary"].text
end

p start_time # => "5429.47"
p binary # => that crazy long binary
```

This REXML tutorial is helpful: http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html

Note, I made a few assumptions, like the elements would always exist, the ms level was always an int, the file structure is always the same. Those assumptions may not be true in your situation but this should be a start.